# Dropbox API PHP - notification request is empty

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have what should be a very simple issue to solve, but I can't figure out what is going wrong.

Just started a project to use the new Dropbox API v2 to receive notifications for file/folder changes. Following the steps provided in the [documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/webhooks#webhooks) provided, but I run into an issue right off the bat.

I've verified the webhook, and I do receive a POST request from Dropbox every time a file is changed, but the POST request just contains an empty array. The code is simple, as I have just begun the project:

```
// USED for initial verification
/*
$challenge = $_GET['challenge'];
echo $challenge;
*/

$postData = $_POST;

$post_dump = print_r($postData, TRUE);
$fpost = fopen('postTester.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fpost, $post_dump);
fclose($fpost);
```

`$postData` is an empty array with `sizeOf()` `0`.

Any ideas?

Here is the updated code with the solution. Very simple fix.

```
$postData = file_get_contents("php://input");

$post_dump = print_r($postData, TRUE);
$fpost = fopen('postTester.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fpost, $post_dump);
fclose($fpost);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because [`$_POST`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) is only for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` `Content-Type`s. The payload delivered by Dropbox webhooks is `application/json`.

It looks like you'll instead want to use [`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php) or [`php://input`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input), depending on your version of PHP.

You can get the raw payload and then [`json_decode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it to get the structured information.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you very much!